# Python : Can't split file in multiple file

Tags: python, file, import

I have a game project where I have my server and my client. I want to split my client and server so it's more easy to read.

I put all the config tkinter windows in a file and I put in the server `from window import *`.

But in the windows file i'm calling a function that is in the client and it doesn't recognize the function `start_server()` when I'm launching the client.

Any suggestions how I can do that ? Thanks for your help !

server.py

```
import socket
import threading
from time import sleep
from window import *

def start_server():
    global server, HOST_ADDR, HOST_PORT  # code is fine without this
    btnStart.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
    btnStop.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
(...)
```

window.py

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Tic-Tac-Toe Server")
window.iconbitmap("logo.ico")
window.config(background='#4065A4')

# Top frame consisting of two buttons widgets (i.e. btnStart, btnStop)
topFrame = tk.Frame(window)
btnStart = tk.Button(topFrame, text="Start", font=("Helvetica", 20), bg='#4065A4', fg='white',
                     command=lambda : start_server())
btnStart.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
btnStop = tk.Button(topFrame, text="Stop", font=("Helvetica", 20), bg='#4065A4', fg='white', command=lambda : stop_server(), state=tk.DISABLED)
btnStop.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
topFrame.pack(side=tk.TOP, pady=(5, 0))

# Middle frame consisting of two labels for displaying the host and port info
middleFrame = tk.Frame(window)
lblHost = tk.Label(middleFrame, font=("Helvetica", 10), bg='#4065A4', fg='white', text = "Address: X.X.X.X")
lblHost.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
lblPort = tk.Label(middleFrame, font=("Helvetica", 10), bg='#4065A4', fg='white', text = "Port:XXXX")
lblPort.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
middleFrame.pack(side=tk.TOP, pady=(5, 0))

# The client frame shows the client area
clientFrame = tk.Frame(window)
lblLine = tk.Label(clientFrame,  font=("Helvetica"), text="Liste des joueurs").pack()
scrollBar = tk.Scrollbar(clientFrame)
scrollBar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
tkDisplay = tk.Text(clientFrame, height=10, width=30)
tkDisplay.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y, padx=(5, 0))
scrollBar.config(command=tkDisplay.yview)
tkDisplay.config(yscrollcommand=scrollBar.set, background="#F4F6F7", highlightbackground="grey", state="disabled")
clientFrame.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, pady=(5, 10))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [mre], [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: I just updated my post with my code and some more details. I hope it's enough.

Comment: Do you ever call `start_server` *from* `client.py`?

Comment: Yes look at the ```btn_start button``` in the window.py. I'm calling ```start_server()```

Comment: .. Is there a statement **in** client.py that calls `start_server`?

Comment: Yes it is. ``` command=lambda: start_server()) ``` in window.py that is calling ```def start_server():``` in server.py (sorry i confused, it's in the server not the client)

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `command=lambda : start_server()` instead of `command=start_server`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind/configure the callback in server.py after `window` has been imported.

window.py

```
...
btnStart = tk.Button(topFrame, text="Start", font=("Helvetica", 20), bg='#4065A4', fg='white')
...
```

server.py

```
...
from window import *
btnStart.configure(command=lambda : start_server())
...
```

---

[Setting options](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html?highlight=tk#setting-options)